# React hooks rendering cause

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-hooks

I'm playing with simple React components to understand when rendering occurs.

[Sample 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-rendering-bo9bp) - Initially renders once. Regardless of the number of times the button is clicked, it doesn't render. This is expected.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "test1" },
    { id: 2, name: "test2" }
  ]);
  const onClick = () => setState(data => data);
  console.log("App rendered");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Test if setting same data causes re-rendering</h1>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Call setState with same data</button>
      {state.map(({ id, name }) => (
        <p key={id}>{name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Sample 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/call-api-with-useeffect-vlo34) - Initially renders twice since `useEffect` updates `setMessages` with a value. This is expected. However, if the button is click 1+ times, it renders once. It shouldn't even re-render since the same value is being set. **Why is it rendering if no new value / reference is being updated?**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

const days = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday"
];
export default function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/10xva4`)
      .then(({ data: { messages } }) => setMessages(messages));
  }, []);
  const Display = useMemo(
    () =>
      messages.map(({ content, senderUuid, sentAt }, index) => {
        let d = new Date(sentAt);
        return (
          <div className="container" key={index}>
            <p>Content: {content}</p>
            <p>SenderUuid: {senderUuid}</p>
            <p>DayOfTheWeek: {d.getDate()}</p>
            <p>Month: {d.getMonth()}</p>
            <p>Day: {days[d.getDay()]}</p>
            <p>Year: {d.getFullYear()}</p>
          </div>
        );
      }),
    [messages]
  );
  const onClick = useCallback(() => setMessages(messages => messages), []);
  console.log("App rendered");
  // console.log({ messages });
  return useMemo(
    () => (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={onClick}>Call setMessages with same data</button>
        {Display}
      </div>
    ),
    [Display, onClick]
  );
}
```

---

UPDATE: Confirmed its a bug with react. - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18098

Comment: There is only "Hello CodeSandbox" in `Sample 1` and no buttons 

Comment: @artanik Updated

Comment: I have to disappear (which isn't helpful), but `setMessages(messages => messages)` doesn't make sense. That's just setting what's already there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder its just to confirm that no rendering occurs if the same value is returned. I could have a function `setMessages(messages => { 
 ...do some work...
return new value or original value;
}`

Comment: There is something happening in useState when you used inside the useEffect, even in first sample, if you pass the value inside the useEffect, it will trigger the component again when you click the button first time.

Comment: @RajKumar `useEffect`'s `setMessage` causes the second render. Thats expected. My question is why `onClick` causes any renders if no references change. Updated codesandbox sample.

Comment: Even this minimal example has the same issue https://codesandbox.io/s/call-api-with-useeffect-bgmwx Looks like a bug with `useEffect`, because without `useEffect` everything is fine

Comment: `useCallback` and `useMemo` didn't help, you can change `onClick` on another useEffect with setTimeout in it and see the same issue https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-rendering-ln2lq also passing `[message]` to `useEffect` didn't help

Comment: @artanik Interesting. Thanks. Thought I was missing some knowledge. Posted as a bug in react's github.